# How to create multiple instances of Mediawiki in a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, mediawiki, kubernetes-pod

I´m about to deploy multiple Mediawiki instances on my Kubernetes-cluster.
In my case the YAML deploymentfile for the DB (MySQL) works as it supposed to do, the deploymentfile for Mediawiki deploys as many pods as expected, but I can´t access them from outside of the cluster even if I create a Service for this case.

If I try to create one single Mediawiki pod and a service to access it from outside of the cluster it works as it should. If I try to create a deploymentfile for Mediawiki equal to the one for MySQL it does creates the pods and the requiered service but it´s not accessible from the externel-IP assigned to it.

My deploymentfile for Mediawiki:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: mediawiki-service
 labels:
  name: mediawiki-service
  app: mediawiki
spec:
 type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
 - port: 80
   targetPort: 80
 selector:
  name: mediawiki-pod
  app: mediawiki
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mediawiki
spec:
  replicas: 6
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mediawiki
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mediawiki
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mediawiki
        name: mediawiki
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: mediawiki
```

This is the pod-definition file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: mediawiki-pod
 labels:
  name: mediawiki-pod
  app: mediawiki
spec:
 containers:
 - name: mediawiki
   image: mediawiki
   ports:
   - containerPort: 80
```

This is the service-definition file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: mediawiki-service
 labels:
  name: mediawiki-service
  app: mediawiki
spec:
 type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
 - port: 80
   targetPort: 80
 selector:
  name: mediawiki-pod
```

The accual resault should be that I can deploy multiple instances of Mediawiki on my cluster and can access them from outside with the externel-IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `kubectl describe service mediawiki-service` in both scenarios, I expect you will see that in the single-pod case, there is an `Endpoints:` list that includes a single IP address (the pod's, but that's an implementation detail) but in the deployment case, it says `<none>`.

Your Service only matches pods that have both `name` and `app` labels:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
spec:
 selector:
  name: mediawiki-pod
  app: mediawiki
```

But the pods deployed by your deployment only have `app` labels:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mediawiki
```

So at that specific point (the labels inside the template for the deployment; also adding them at the top level doesn't hurt, but this embedded point is what's important) you need to add the second label `name: mediawiki-pod`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy multiple instances of some piece of software on Kubernetes cluster it's good idea to check out if there is a [helm](https://helm.sh) chart for it.
In your case the answer is positive - there is a [stable helm chart for Mediawiki](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mediawiki).

Creating multiple instances is as easy as creating multiple releases, for example:

```
helm install --name wiki1 stable/mediawiki
helm install --name wiki2 stable/mediawiki
helm install --name wiki3 stable/mediawiki
```

To use Helm you have to install it on your local machine and on k8s cluster - following the [quick start guide](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#quickstart) will be enough.